# Error : match invalid bye sequence in US-ASCII

Tags: ruby

I need your help.
For the work i need to manage a new workstation et recreate the same environment and in this environment I need to run a script in Ruby and i have an error :
match invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
The line : next if line.match(/^#/)
Could you help me ?
Thanks

I tested to add a the top of the file #encoding : UTF-8 or ISO but when I do that I have a new error with else syntax.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

`# encoding: utf-8` is a hint to tell older Ruby interpreters what the encoding of your Ruby *script* is. That's not really what you need.

Try running your script with `ruby -E utf-8:utf-8`. That sets the [external and internal encoding](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/IO.html#class-IO-label-Open+Options) to UTF-8. That means all input strings are assumed to be encoded as UTF-8 and that encoding is also used for the String objects within the script.